# save and load complex struct (codable) to local file in swift 4 - Xcode

Tags: json, swift, database, xcode, struct

I am programming a game and saved all user relevant data to as "UserDefaults.standard".

In the game characters are created which are a little more complex (example):

```
struct Champ:  Codable {
    var id: String = ""
    var owner: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var released: Bool = false
    var images: CharacterImage? 
    var charClass: CharClass = CharClass(rawValue: 0)!
    var hp: HealthPoints = HealthPoints(current: 0, max: 0)
    var skills : [Int] = [0]
}
```

In the game I just handle them as an array of [Character].
Storing this array to UserDefaults gives an error, because I believe it is too big.

What is the simplest way to save and retrieve such a complex struct?

e.g.:

```
saveArray([Champ], toFile: "character.txt")

characters = loadArray([Champ], fromFile: "character.txt")
```

I was experimenting with JSON and saving seems to work, but I cannot load the data properly.

```
                   var characters: [Champ] = [...]
                   let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    if let jsondata = try? encoder.encode(characters),
                        let jsonstr = String(data: jsondata, encoding: .utf8) {
                            print(jsonstr)

                    try jsonstr.write(toFile: myfile.path,
                                          atomically: true,
                                          encoding: .utf8)
                    }
```

Solution provided by Leo Dabus:

```
   let encoder = JSONEncoder()
   if let jsondata = try? encoder.encode(characters) {
      print(jsondata)
      try jsondata.write(to: docurl.appendingPathComponent("Characters.txt"), options: .atomic)}

   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   let CharReadData = try? Data(contentsOf: docurl.appendingPathComponent("Characters.txt"), options: .init())
   let newData = try? decoder.decode([Champ].self, from: CharReadData!)
                    dump(newData)
```

Comment: You should choose a different name for your custom structure considering that Character it is already a native Swift structure type.

Comment: regarding your issue `CharacterImage`, `CharClass` and `HealthPoints` should conform to Codable as well

Comment: they do. I think 200 lines of characters is just too much for the UserDefaults.
struct HealthPoints: Codable {
    var current: Int = 0
    var max: Int = 0
    
}

struct ManaPoints: Codable {
    var current: Int = 0
    var max: Int = 0
    
    init(current: Int, max: Int) {
        self.current = current
        self.max = max
    }
}

struct CharacterImage: Codable {
    var imagesId: [Int]?
    var imagesColor: [Int]? 
    
    init(images: [Int], colors: [Int]) {
        self.imagesId = images
        self.imagesColor = colors
    }
}

Comment: Just save the data to a plist file or to a json file

Comment: Why are you converting the data to a string and then writing that.  Just save the data:  `try jsondata.write(to: myfile.path, options: .atomic)`.  And if you are still getting errors with loading, show your loading code and the errors you get.

Comment: ok I made the changes. It seems to save, output is: 11452 bytes.
When I want to read it, it gives me just the byte code... Optional(11452 bytes)
                        let CharReadData = try? Data(contentsOf: docurl.appendingPathComponent("Characters.txt"), options: .alwaysMapped)
                        print(CharReadData)

How can I define it to read it as [Character]?

Comment: First unwrap your data then use JSONDecoder to decode it `let chars = try JSONDecoder().decode([ACharacter].self, from: data)`

Comment: Again you should rename your structure

Comment: great, that fixed it. Thank you, this is amazing and helps me a lot. I will rename the struct when rewriting the code. :D